# Javascript Perlin noise implementation. Artifacts and value bound

Tags: javascript, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I am trying to understand Perlin noise, but I am having two main issues:
the value I get out of the function I wrote seems to never reach values near the extremes (0, 1). The other issue is that the image I get spit out does not remotely resemble a Perlin noise generated image.
Code split in sections. All code appears in order.

Seeded PNRG for permutations of array `p`, and add `Math.lerp` and `ctx.drawPixel`

```
const SEED = [0x12345678, 0x9ABCDEF0, 0x12345678, 0x9ABCDEF0];
const fade = function (t) {
    return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
};
Math.lerp = function (a, b, f) {
    return a + fade(f) * (b - a);
};
Math.seededPNRG = function (a, b, c, d) {
    return function() {
        a >>>= 0; b >>>= 0; c >>>= 0; d >>>= 0;
        let t = (a + b) | 0;
        a = b ^ b >>> 9;
        b = c + (c << 3) | 0;
        c = (c << 21 | c >>> 11);
        d = d + 1 | 0;
        t = t + d | 0;
        c = c + t | 0;
        return (t >>> 0) / 4294967296;
    }
};
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawPixel = function (x,y) {
    this.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
};
```

Generate permutation of the array (Knuth shuffle)

```
const random = Math.seededPNRG(...SEED);
const p = [];
{
    for (let i=0; i<256; i++)
        p[i] = i;
    let j, t;
    for (let i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        j = i + Math.floor(random() * (256 - i));
        t = p[i];
        p[i] = p[j];
        p[j] = t;
    }
    p.push(...p);
}
```

Actual Perlin noise generator

```
const perlin = function (x, y, z) {
    x = x % 512;
    y = y % 512;
    z = z % 512;
    let xi = x & 255, yi = y & 255, zi = z & 255;
    let xf = x - Math.floor(x), yf = y - Math.floor(y), zf = z - Math.floor(z);
    let u = fade(xf), v = fade(yf), w = fade(zf);
    let aaa, aba, aab, abb, baa, bba, bab, bbb;
    {
        let inc = n => n+1;
        aaa = p[p[p[    xi ]+    yi ]+    zi ];
        aba = p[p[p[    xi ]+inc(yi)]+    zi ];
        aab = p[p[p[    xi ]+    yi ]+inc(zi)];
        abb = p[p[p[    xi ]+inc(yi)]+inc(zi)];
        baa = p[p[p[inc(xi)]+    yi ]+    zi ];
        bba = p[p[p[inc(xi)]+inc(yi)]+    zi ];
        bab = p[p[p[inc(xi)]+    yi ]+inc(zi)];
        bbb = p[p[p[inc(xi)]+inc(yi)]+inc(zi)];
    }
    const grad = function (hash, x, y, z) {
        let h = hash & 15;
        let u = h < 8 ? x : y;
        let v;
        if (h < 4)
            v = y;
        else if (h === 12 || h === 14)
            v = x;
        else v = z;
        return (h & 1 === 0 ? u : -u)+(h & 2 === 0 ? v : -v);
    };
    let x1, x2, y1, y2;
    x1 = Math.lerp(
        grad(aaa, xf, yf, zf),
        grad(baa, xf-1, yf, zf),
        u
    );
    x2 = Math.lerp(
        grad(aba, xf, yf-1, zf),
        grad(bba, xf-1, yf-1, zf),
        u
    );
    y1 = Math.lerp(x1, x2, v);
    x1 = Math.lerp(
        grad(aab, xf, yf, zf-1),
        grad(bab, xf-1, yf, zf-1),
        u
    );
    x2 = Math.lerp(
        grad(abb, xf, yf-1, zf-1),
        grad(bbb, xf-1, yf-1, zf-1),
        u
    );
    y2 = Math.lerp(x1,x2,v);
    return (Math.lerp(y1, y2, w) + 1) / 2;
};
```

Draw image

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const height = canvas.height;
const width = canvas.width;

for (let i=100; i<width-200; i++) {
    for (let j=100; j<height-200; j++) {
        let k = perlin(i/100, j/100,.5);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#"+Math.floor(k * 256).toString(16).repeat(3);
        ctx.drawPixel(i, j);
    }
}
```

Any tip appreciated. Really no idea where the issue might come from.
Edit: this is the "guide" I used: https://flafla2.github.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html